# Niveles o acceso de usuario por tipo de rol

Tags: php, php7

Tengo acceso por roles a un sistema con distintas pantallas, en algunas de ellas el contenido de pantalla puede ser el mismo, solo cambia el "header".

Es decir estas pantallas puede ser que una sea para "operario" otra para "supervisor", pero el contenido principal es lo mismo para ambas, solo cambia el header, esto lo cambio con require() de PHP o es la idea que tengo.

```
<?php
    // Includes y Requires
    require('../includes/configuraciones.php');
    require('../includes/funciones.php');

    // Autorizacion de acceso por tipo de rol
    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario_pb'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['usuario_pb']['id_cargo'] != 2) {
            header('Location:../index.php');
        } 
    } else {
        header('Location:../index.php');
    }

    // Includes y Requires
    require('../database/database.php');
    // Aquí es donde dependiendo del valor en la session seleccione header (pregunta 2)
    require('../includes/header.php');
?>
```

Cómo pueden observar hay una sentencia if que valida la $_SESSION en la posición "id_cargo", donde si es diferente de 2 hace una redirección a index.php, entonces mis dudas son:

¿Cómo le hago en caso de que tenga más id_cargo, por ejemplo 1 (supervisor) y 3 (gerencia)? Si, en este caso fuera 2, se queda en pantalla para operario si no se va a login. Intentente hacerlo con un switch case o con un if-else o incluso en el mismo if aplicar un operador or (||) validando con 1 y 3, pero me da el error **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

```
if ($_SESSION['usuario_pb']['id_cargo'] != 2) {
    header('Location:../index.php');
}
if ($_SESSION['usuario_pb']['id_cargo'] != 1) {
    header('Location:../index.php');
}
```

¿Cómo le hago para que dependiendo del 'id_cargo' seleccione el header del rol logueado?

Comment: por qué haces `header('Location:../index.php');`? Y qué esperas con los `require`s después de este `if`: `if (isset($_SESSION['usuario_pb'])) {`?

Comment: Lo hago para "redireccionar" de un fichero PHP a otro, ¿Qué espero? Los valores que se guardan en las posiciones del array de $_SESSION['usuario_pb'] solo los valores de la consulta a la base de datos, tales como usuario, contraseña así como tipo de rol (id_cargo)

Comment: Ya, es el objetivo de `header()`. Preguntaba por el hecho de en qué directorio estás ejecutando tu script. Qué hay en `../index.php`?

Comment: El archivo index.php redirecciona a login.php, de aquí se va al script php para consulta a la tabla de usuarios y es donde se llena el array de $_SESSION['usuario_pb']

Comment: A ver si entiendo bien: `../index.,php` redirecciona a `login.php` y login al script este y este script vuelve a index, que vuelve a login y así sucesivamente...

Comment: Index a login, login hace la petición a la base y redireciona a la pantalla para el rol del usuario logueado